# What is the trigonometric form of the complex variable $z=0+0i $?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm confused how do i determine the trigonometric form of the complex variable $z=0+0i$ , it has modula such that is 0 but what about it's argument ?

**Note** : At a least i would like to know it's geometric intrepretation

Thank you for any help

Comment: It is the origin on the complex plane.

Comment: The argument is undefined (any argument would be valid, really). It's one of the imperfections in the trigonometric system.

Comment: What is the longitude of the North or South Pole on a globe?

Comment: One little remark. $0+0i$ is not a variable, it is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometric representation of a complex number is $r(cos(\theta)+ i sin(\theta))$.  For 0, r= 0 and $\theta$ becomes irrelevant.

Comment: This does not answer the question: give a trigonometric form of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's just $z=0$. For any $\phi$, we have
$$z=0e^{i\phi}=0(cos\phi+i\sin\phi) = 0$$

You can think of this as the zero vector. It is trivially unaffected by rotation. We can add any arbitrary phase to zero, and it remains zero.

Comment: This does not answer the question: give a trigonometric form of $0$.

Comment: Could you explain? The trig form of a complex number is $r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$. If the modulus is zero, the phase is meaningless.

Comment: So, what is the trigonometric form of $0$? Can you write it?